# How to create a form validation rule by passing a function?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to create a rule for a form field that allows me to compare the value of that field with the various elements of an array. At the moment, I have something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form" >
          <v-text-field v-model="id" :rules="[...rules.required,...rules.repeatedID]"/>
  </v-form>
</template

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data() {    
    return{
       idQuestoes: [] //Array that gets populated from GET request
       rules: {
          required: [(v) => !!v || "Field is required"],
          repeatedID: [v => checkID(v) || "ID already exists"],
       }
   
  created() { 
    // Populating the array with values from database
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/question`)
      .then((response)=>{
        response.data.forEach((obj) =>{
          this.idQuestoes = obj.id
        });
      },(error) =>{
          console.log(error);
    });
 
   methods: {

    checkID(item){
      this.idQuestoes.forEach((value) =>{
        if(value == item){
          return false
        }
      }) 
    }
   }

</script>
```

Most of the code is just the populating of the array with the values coming from the database, which are simply Strings. The issue I'm running into at the moment is that it's saying that checkID is undefined.

Am I able to solve the problem or is this solution just not going to work at all? I'm open to other ideas to make this form validation rule work.

Also, if I'm missing some code to make sure everything is working, it's because there's already a lot, so I tried to keep it to a bare minimum.

Comment: `this.idQuestoes = obj.id` I don't think this is doing what you think it is. It doesn't look like it is populating an array. It looks like it is setting `this.idQuestoes` to an int.

Comment: I've tested it and that part is working properly, using it in another places. But I'll give it a review. Still, I don't think the problem I'm having would be because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use component methods, the method name needs to be prefixed with `this.`:

```js
repeatedID: [v => this.checkID(v) || "ID already exists"],
```

Also, `checkID()` should use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for an existing ID in the array:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    checkID(item) {
      return !this.idQuestoes.find(x => x === item)
    },
  },
}
```

Also, the `axios` callback should be using `Array.prototype.push()` to append the `obj.id`s to `idQuestoes[]`, or use `Array.prototype.map()` to map the API response into `id`s:

```js
axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/question`)
  .then((response)=> {

    response.data.forEach((obj) =>{
      //this.idQuestoes = obj.id ❌

      this.idQuestoes.push(obj.id) ✅
    });

    // OR
    this.idQuestoes = response.data.map(x => x.id)
  })
```

[demo](http://codesandbox.io/s/form-validation-rules-in-vuetify-nfu94?file=/src/components/MyForm.vue)

Comment: Damn, can't believe I missed the fact that the problem was because of the this keyword. Every once in a while I do the same mistake... Also thanks for the rest.